# Association Rule Mining in python on Census Data

Tags: python, associations, data-mining, rules, apriori

**Hello everyone, I am working on a project. I need to perform Association Rule Mining on a Census Data Which Looks Like the image given below.**[image: Census Data]

**I am using the Apriori Algorithm from the mlxtend library. Here is the Code.**

```
# Library Imports
import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules

# Reading the Data File
data = pd.read_csv("Census.csv")

# Reading Certain Columns of the Data File.
df = data[["Region","Residence Type","Sex","Student"]]

# Initializing the Transaction Encoder 
te = TransactionEncoder()

# Fitting the Data.
te_ary = te.fit(df).transform(df)

# Creating a Dataframe of Support and Element name
df2 = pd.DataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)

# Calling in the Apriori Algorithm.
fre = apriori(df2,min_support=0.6,use_colnames=True)

# Calling the Association Rule Function.
association_rules(fre, metric="confidence",min_threshold=0.7)
```

**But the `fre` variable does not returns any rules, it is always empty. Can someone help me please.It is request.**

Comment: Do you mean that your variable `fre`, which holds the return of the `apriori` function call is always empty?

Comment: Yes sir it is Empty

Comment: I mean the min_support of 0.6 is pretty high...

Comment: At Initial I used my Calculated value of 0.047 @Feelx234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many ways and a friend of mine suggested me a way for solving my problem. It worked in a graceful way, but yes it requires your logic too.
This is the link which helped me to implement my question in a better way, [here it is](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-apriori-algorithm-in-python/).
In my solution I used correlating parameters and created a basket.

This is it. Thank you.